# How to go to any buffer directly by searching the contents of all buffers in Vim, like pressing Ctrl+P in Sublime Text?

Tags: search, vim, hotkeys, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, when I have a bunch of files opening, I can go to any opened file by 3 following steps:

1. Hit `<Ctrl>+P`.
2. Enter the pattern to search for. The editor immediately display the file which match the pattern while I am typing (without hitting `<Enter>`).
3. After the right file is shown, I hit `<Enter>` to select the file.

How can I have similar functionality in Vim to search through all buffers/tabs? I know there are plenty of plugins which allow me to search all buffers, but they are just not as simple as the above 3 steps to go to a file. I think this feature is particularly useful in navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the vim [CtrlP Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) to search through all files in your current working directory (`:pwd`, changed with `:cd dir`) or you can use the [Lusty Explorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) plugin to search through all open buffers in vim

With CtrlP, it you would type ctrl+p, then the file pattern, then enter (or ctrl-t to open in a new tab)

With Lusty, you would type Leader lb (leader is \ by default), type the name of the buffer you have open, and hit enter or ctrl-t

Comment: Thanks. I got Lusty and the feature that I want is to type Leader lg. :-)